# How to show that this limit is tend to zero?

Tags: calculus, limits

How to show that this limit is tend to zero?
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n!}}{(1+\sqrt{1})(1+\sqrt{2})\cdots(1+\sqrt{n})}=0$$
Thank you.

Comment: See [convergence criteria for infinite products](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_product#Convergence_criteria). Also, note that an infinite product is said to *diverge* to $0$

Comment: @Lucian I've never heard of anything diverging on $0$. I'm sure you meant diverging to $\infty$ (or converge to $0$)

Comment: @Cruncher: Check the link. It also contains an explanation.

Answer (score 15):

You have 
$$\frac{\sqrt{n!}}{(1+\sqrt 1)(1+\sqrt 2)\cdots (1+\sqrt{n})}=\frac1{\left(1+\frac1{\sqrt1}\right)\left(1+\frac1{\sqrt2}\right)\cdots \left(1+\frac1{\sqrt {n}}\right)}\cdot $$
So you need to show that 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \prod_{k=1}^n \left(1+\frac1{\sqrt{k}}\right)=\infty\, ; $$
in other words, that the infinite product $\prod \left(1+\frac1{\sqrt{k}}\right)$ is divergent to $\infty$.

This is true because the series $\sum\frac1{\sqrt{k}}$ is divergent.

Answer (score 4):

Notice 
$$k = (k-1)+1 \le (\sqrt{k-1}+1)^2\quad\implies\quad\sqrt{k} \le \sqrt{k-1}+1,$$
we have
$$0 \le \frac{\sqrt{n!}}{\prod\limits_{k=1}^n (1+\sqrt{k})} = \prod_{k=1}^n \frac{\sqrt{k}}{\sqrt{k}+1} \le \prod_{k=1}^n \frac{\sqrt{k-1}+1}{\sqrt{k}+1} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}+1}$$
Since the RHS goes to $0$ as $n \to \infty$, we find
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sqrt{n!}}{\prod\limits_{k=1}^n (1+\sqrt{k})} = 0$$

Comment: How about [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/760451/evaluate-displaystyle-lim-j-to0-lim-k-to-infty-frackjj-ek)?

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite your expression as

$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\Pi_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\sqrt{i}}{1+\sqrt{i}}=
\\
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\Pi_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{i}}+1}
$

Now, we know that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}=0$. You can go from there.

Comment: @GregVoigt Your proof is not correct. The statement does not follow from the fact that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{\sqrt{n}}=0$

Comment: @GregVoigt I am *not* the downvoter...

Answer (score 0):

Other ways to increase:

1)$$0 < \frac{\sqrt{n!}}{\prod\limits_{k=1}^n (1+\sqrt{k})} = \prod_{k=1}^n \frac{\sqrt{k}}{\sqrt{k}+1} < \prod_{k=1}^n \sqrt{\frac{k}{k+1}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}} \to 0$$

2) Apply mathematical induction can be demonstrated:
$$ \prod_{k=1}^n \frac{\sqrt{k}}{\sqrt{k}+1} < \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \to 0$$